# .htaccess doesn't rewrite the URL as it should

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+) user.php?proc=$1
```

When I go to: `http://localhost/user/register/`, and try to `echo` the variable `$_GET["proc"]`, I get: `register.php` instead of `register`. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordering of your rules seems to be a problem here.

Keep your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+) /user.php?proc=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /$1.php

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php [L]
```